# Robot Coverage Path Planning

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings!

I am working on a project which requires complete coverage of a room.
So given some map, how can i traverse every "open cell" (no obstacle) of that room.
This is similar to the autonomous lawn mowing where the robot must cover all the grass and not miss an area.

Is there a ROS package for complete coverage? I have looked and found a couple packages but im not quite sure what i should be looking for or where to start.

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239267/robot-coverage-path-planning/) by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on 2020-08-12**:
Hi @RoSPlebb, may I check if you manage to implement the complete coverage program? I have tried the heatmap package but it seems that it only plan for complete coverage of a polygon drawn by rviz's publish_point and not complete coverage of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When asking this kind of question in the future, please include links to the reference material that you've already found, and maybe a short explanation of why it doesn't seem to work for you.

This is particularly important because this question has been asked a number of times before:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/212614/complete-coverage-path-planning-ros/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/214123/make-robot-go-very-close-to-the-obstacles-complete-coverage-path-planning/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/174998/path-planning-for-sensortool-coverage/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/213625/following-a-boustrophedon-path-in-a-given-room-with-obstacles/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/185718/full-coverage-path-planner/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/203867/how-to-instruct-a-robot-to-cover-the-whole-mapped-2d-area/

From those questions, the heatmap package has been recommended several times and sounds promising: http://wiki.ros.org/heatmap

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on 2016-07-11**:
I apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for the help i appreciate it!